# delete specific lines and insert new line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, readlines

I got a hardship dealing with some python codes.
I've browsed many questions which ask similar questions, but
literally I couldn't find keys to solve my problem.

what I really want to do is to delete whole specific paragraph that has random contents
(which means, for the example below, from 'paragraph_a' to parenthesis')' )
by using the name of 'paragraph_b' in code.

Here is an input text file format of my code.

```
some random texts (100+ lines)

...

paragraph_a A_story(    
...
some random texts
...
)

paragraph_b different_story(
...
some random texts
...
)
```

and below is the desired output

```
some random texts (100+ lines)

...

story "A is deleted"

paragraph_b different_story(
...
some random texts
...
)
```

To sum up,

Here summarizes what I want to do.

1. delete paragraph_a by using the name of the next paragraph(paragraph_b) in the code.
   (I think I need to set the clear range for this.)
2. and then, Add certain text like: story "A is deleted" on the deleted part.

I've tried open input files on read mode generated output files on write mode
and by readlines() then I made some flags which only becomes '1' if not read paragraph_a.

but It only deletes the first line of the paragraph..

below code is I've tried so far

```
def erase(file_name: str, start_key: str, stop_key: str):
    try: 
        # read the file lines
        with open('input.txt', 'r+') as fr: 
            lines = fr.readlines()
        # write the file lines except the start_key until the stop_key
        with open('output.txt', 'w+') as fw:

            delete = False

            for line in lines:

                if line.strip('\n') == start_key:
                     delete = True

                elif line.strip('\n') == stop_key:
                     delete = False

                if not delete:
                    fw.write(line)
    except RuntimeError as ex: 
        print(f"erase error:\n\t{ex}")

def main():
    erase('input.txt','paragraph_a','paragraph_b')

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

but the output becomes same as input..

How can I deal with this?
Any answer or clue would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the actual target paragraph start with `paragraph_a A_story(` and end with `)`?  If not, can you add the real text?

Comment: Yes, It starts like that and ends with ) as u said.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can u please give any example code that I can refer to?  I stucked for hours...

Comment: Can you share a code snippet, something to work from, besides the description of the problem?

Comment: @EmmanuelMurairi I added the code I 've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a multiline regex on the file content as a whole,

```
r"^(\w+ \w+\((?:(.|\n)*)\))\s*^paragraph_b"
```

and then replace the matching group.

See the regex in action here: https://regex101.com/r/pwGVbe/1

Python's `re` module provides this functionality to you.

Comment: Thanks!! Do I use that like 
        newline = re.sub(r'^(\w+ \w+\((?:(.|\n)*)\))\s*^paragraph_b', '', line)
and write the newline to the output?

Comment: Can you please give me any detailed example? it seems work but when I tried, actually didn't replace anything..

Comment: As I had written, you need to use the regex on the content as a whole. Not on single lines. As it is a multiline regex and includes several lines.